# get data with angular firestore

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I am new to angular firestore and I'm trying to get data from firestore. I have the following code:

```
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {
    myArray: any[] = []
    constructor(private authService: AuthService, public afs: AngularFirestore) {}

    test = this.afs.collection('doctors').get().subscribe((ss) => {
        ss.docs.forEach((doc) => {this.myArray.push(doc.data()); });
    });
}
```

In my html file, I'm trying to display myArray like this:

```
<li *ngFor='let doc of myArray'>
     {{doc}}
</li>
```

I know that my array reads the table 'doctors' correctly in my firebase since it prints three object which is the number of element in my table doctors right now, but I get the following output in html:

[image]

Could someone help me to display the values correctly? Table doctors have an email, firstname and lastname. I would like to print email of each entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to display the data using the `json` pipe, like this:

```js
<li *ngFor='let doc of myArray'>
     {{doc | json}}
</li>
```

The `json` pipe is necessary when you want to display an object and it's mostly useful for debugging. More info in the docs:
[Angular - JsonPipe](https://angular.io/api/common/JsonPipe)

Comment: thank you so much! I can see all the datas! Now how can I print only the email value? I get the following for the first entity { "lastName": "Sdf", "firstName":, "email": "sadasd@assf.co" }

Comment: Just  have {{ doc.email }}